# Has a commercial aircraft ever taken off with its landing gear up?

Tags: takeoff, landing-gear

In the extremely scientifically accurate movie Airplane the Autopilot takes off with the gear up.

Has this ever happened? Could any commercial or 4+ passenger GA aircraft do this, say with a 1%+ chance of not crashing?

Maybe with a smooth, small ditch that would guide the body and/or grass it could doable. The belly would certainly be warm! (Or on fire)

Silly question, but didn't find anything about it online.

Comment: Yes sure, any flying boat does :)

Comment: I don't have any authoritative evidence on this, but I expect the friction of the ground would prevent the aircraft reaching takeoff speed. There might also be some difficulties in raising the nose.

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder not only that, but most airplanes also need to rotate (raise the nose to increase angle of attack and therefore lift) on take off, and wouldn't be able to do it without the gear.

Comment: Ski equipped LC-130's take off this way from arctic & antarctic snow packs... wheels down to operate on conventional runways, wheels up to operate on the snow. If I have time to find a good photo, I'll post as an answer, although anyone else is welcome to as well.

Comment: @RalphJ, I would could the skis as (a special kind of) landing gear though.

Comment: @JanHudec  If the skis are all that you've got (like photo in Mike Sowsun's post, or a pure airplane-on-skis), I'd entirely agree.  On an LC-130, the wheels are still there, but they are extended/retracted thru the skis, so the case could be made that it's still a "gear up" takeoff -- especially since the skis can't be retracted.  But this is an exercise in terminology more than in what the OP was asking about, so I'm not inclined to pursue this thought much further.

Comment: @RalphJ that's just two alternative landing gears, with the LC-130 being unusual in that the skis, when equipped, are not retractable (on most aircraft when skis are mounted, they move with the gear).

Comment: Thinking about it: It can only be on the belly if it has before *landed* with the gear up, right? (If we exclude experiments or technical verification.) It would most likely not be in flight worthy condition after that, surely not nominally. The only conceivable scenario for a gear-up start would be after an emergency landing in a remote place without the option to repair or leave without the plane.

Comment: *the Autopilot*  Get it right.  [That's Otto Pilot.](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1290293/)  :-D

Answer (score 25):

Excluding planes that use something else than landing gear for take-off—seaplanes, using launch rails, or air-launched—there was one accident where a plane went around after landing gear up by mistake: [Crash: PIA A320 at Karachi on May 22nd 2020, impacted residential area during final approach, both engines failed as result of a gear up touchdown](https://avherald.com/h?article=4d7a6e9a). Two points to take from that accident:

1. The plane was only able to lift off again because it still had way higher than normal take-off speed. Since sitting on the engines does not allow as high pitch attitude as normal rotation on gear, the angle of attack is lower and so higher speed is needed to get the same lift.
2. The damage to the engines caused during the event caused them to both fail in a minute or so.

That shows it's unlikely it would be possible to take off this way from stand-still. Of course this does not show no plane could do that, but most commercial aircraft are similar in that regard. They are designed stay intact enough on a gear-up landing so the people on board won't be injured, but will be damaged enough that they won't be able to take off without repairs.

Side note: the autopilot can't start the engines on its own and the pilots would hopefully not be insane enough to do that with airplane sitting on its belly.

Comment: Comments on that link mention "a Tu-154 touching down with landing gear retracted, skidding a solid 650m on the runway while the engines spooled up, lifting off again for another approach and landing successfully."  Another commenter points out that its tail-mounted engines will keep them out of harms way while scraping the belly, unlike the A320 accident aircraft.  So this idea is a non-starter for an A320, but maybe not for other designs.

Comment: @PeterCordes … thanks; fortunately there is even a reference: [Malév flight 262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal%C3%A9v_Flight_262). While the tail-mounted engines would not be damaged, it really surprises me the plane was able to lift off again, because the bottom of the aircraft is flat so without gear it cannot raise the nose to get enough lift.

Comment: The fuselage curves upward some distance ahead of the elevators; maybe at the speed they were going (with engines already spooling up *before* touchdown) that short lever arm was enough for the pitch authority the elevators could provide?  (Compared to how far the center of mass was ahead of the centre of lift from the wings, which is what the tail would have to balance on the other end of that lever.)

Answer (score 8):

Just a raw estimation to be added to the other answers:

At takeoff, engine's thrust is used to accelerate the airplane and to overcome aerodynamic drag plus rolling resistance of the landing gears. Or, in the case of our sliding airplane, the sliding friction.

In order to understand if making the airplane slide on its belly instead of rolling on its tires is doable, let's ballpark estimate these four terms (acceleration, aerodynamic drag, rolling resistance and sliding friction). No worries, just a couple of simple multiplications.

1. Acceleration: since the airplane has to reach the same takeoff speed within the same airfield's length both with and without landing gears, then it has to accelerate in the same way for both cases; from [basic physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration), acceleration is $a=V²/2L$  and for Newton's second law the relevant force to be applied is $F=ma=mV²/2L$ where $m$ is the airplane's mass, $V$ the takeoff speed and $L$ the field's length. Let's use a B747 to do the maths (SI units):
   $F=(370'000\times85²)/(2\times3'300)=405kN$
2. Drag: let's evaluate it just before takeoff which is where the highest value is reached before (any kind of) landing gears become useless; we use the usual drag equation $D=½\rho V²SC_d$ at sea level with $C_d=0.02$ as given in the [B747's polar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/94896/what-fraction-of-fuel-is-consumed-just-for-keeping-a-plane-in-the-air/94905#94905):
   $D=½\times1.125 \times85² \times511 \times0.02=40kN$
3. Rolling resistance; this is simply the weight times a coefficient which depends on the materials; for tire on asphalt this is some 0.03:
   $F_{roll}=370'000 \times 0.03=11kN$
4. Sliding friction; also in this case it is simply the weight times a friction coefficient that for [steel](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267595402_Friction_Between_Steel_and_Asphalt_Without_Gouging_Under_Representative_Rollover_Impact_Pressures) (I couldn't find aluminium) on asphalt is more or less 1:
   $F_{slide}=370'000 \times 1=370kN$

So, let's do the sum to get the needed thrust $T$ for the case with landing gears (1.+2.+3.) and without (1.+2.+4.) respectively:

$T=405+40+11=456kN$

vs.

$T=405+40+370=815kN$

The latter represents an increase of some 80% in respect to a takeoff with landing gears... most probably not feasible.

Comment: Wing moving through the air needs to be pushed with a force that is typically between 0.05 and 0.10 of the weight it is carrying. A bit more at the high angle of attack occurring at take-off. Since commercial aircraft have to be able to continue flying with one engine inoperative, with all engines it needs at least 0.2, but usually around 0.3 of its weight. If the coefficient of friction of aluminum on tarmac was just 0.1, the engines would have plenty of power to accelerate it. I don't think it's that low at the weights involved though.

Comment: … remember, we are not talking about asphalt and aluminum ski sliding on it, we are talking about tarmac (asphalt-glued gravel) and normal forces under which the aluminum piece is abraded rapidly.

Comment: @JanHudec: you're definitely right, I was just considering the very beginning of the takeoff. I'm going to update my answer with a more general approach.

Comment: @JanHudec: done!

Comment: The ground friction will reduce some with speed as the wings take some of the weight, if the plane has enough thrust to overcome static friction.  Maybe some high power/thrust-to-weight craft like a learjet?  Or a turboprop?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust-to-weight_ratio#Aircraft_2 shows Concorde with a TWR of 0.372 (full fuel, full afterburners), and a Tupolev 154B at 0.360.  vs. a Boeing 747-8 at 0.269 (MTOW, full power).  None of the wiki examples are turboprops (which IIUC have good low-speed thrust, and might have lower takeoff speed which would require less F x v = friction power)

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, off the top of my head I'd say a 10% on MTOW is taken from lift, but then we have to add the relevant induced drag.

Comment: Now, that could change a lot if we're looking at an *empty* 747, 757, or 777 (or whatever), with say 1 hour of fuel and an empty cargo bay (no seats or anything). https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=747169  . (Concorde is a good choice for thrust-to-weight, but its high takeoff speed makes it a terrible choice for this.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: well, actually a B747 has some 1'000kN of thrust, so it might be able to roll anyway. But then you have obviously to forget OEI takeoff-roll from hot&high airport. And obviously the rotation at the end of the airfield would be impossible ;)

Comment: Would there also be a reduction of lift with the wings that much closer to the ground?

Comment: @WGroleau: a reduction in induced drag aka drag due to lift

Comment: If that is a "raw estimation" I'd hate to see a detailed one!  Nice!

Comment: @MarkStewart: there would have been a lot of integrals 

Answer (score 5):

[Amphibious aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_aircraft). These only have the  gear down when taking off from the ground, not from the water. For instance, de Havilland Canada [Twin Otter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_DHC-6_Twin_Otter) can be configured as amphibious, it was used by multiple airlines and with 19-20 passengers it is quite an airliner.

Rocket launched (Space Shuttle) or air dropped (X-15) aircraft also  use the landing gear only for landing but the most known examples are not commercial. [SpaceShipTwo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipTwo) however seems commercial at least in the plans.

While the unprepared land base aircraft may have enough engine power  at least on ice, I cannot imagine how it could maintain the necessary orientation without the landing gear while taking off.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the other answers, I think what you’re asking is whether an aircraft could or has taken off where undercarriage would normally be extended.  I can’t say that this has never happened but it seems most unlikely.  Propeller-driven aircraft would typically have the prop touch the ground with the wheels retracted, but that wouldn’t be the case for a jet, which would likely have a high enough thrust/weight ratio to overcome friction, especially on a wet runway.  That raises the question of why any pilot would attempt this; if the undercarriage was inoperative then they would be faced with a wheels-up landing.  If they were attempting to steal a plane then why not choose one with its undercarriage extended.  There are more unlikely scenarios but I don’t need to list them here.  The only definitive answer would be from someone who has seen/executed this manoeuvre, if it’s never happened then it’s unanswerable.

Comment: I don't think any plane could take off like that, but one *went around* like that—and crashed due to the damage it caused.

Comment: Note that wheels-up *landing* is not a huge deal—all planes are designed so that if they land wheel-up (on runway or other sufficiently flat ground), they remain sufficiently intact to avoid injury for the people on board.

Comment: May happen if there is some danger on the ground so grave that attempting to take off with such an aircraft becomes an option. Like enemy advancing, for instance.

Comment: @Jan Hudec - a 737 has a thrust/weight ratio of about 0.3 so it would struggle to move on a dry surface but may do better on a wet runway.  Once it started moving the left from the wings would reduce friction from the ground.

Comment: @h22: the problem is that if the plane has engines low, they will be damaged and won't work for long (as happened in case of PK-8303) while if the engines are high the airplane sits on the fuselage and has no way to rotate and thus increase lift to actually take off.

Comment: The most likely case for a commercial airplane taking off "gear up" would be a large floatplane (eg. a float-equipped Twin Otter) taking off from a grass runway on the floats.

Comment: @h22 You can always beg an advancing army for mercy, physics rarely responds well to that and there are cleaner ways to kill yourself if that's the goal.

Comment: Although the thing sounds extremely perilous, the argument that it just might work does get a boost from ground effect.

Answer (score 4):

Float planes and flying boats have taken off from snow or ice in the past.

Here are two Videos of a Cessna float plane taking off from a frozen lake.

[Cessna 185 taking off on the ice with floats - Red Lake, Ontario](https://vimeo.com/127965727)

[Off the ice on floats, Red Lake](https://youtu.be/zkNdywHVOnQ)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Malév Flight 262 performed a gears-up touchdown, skidded on the runway for 650 meters, then took off again and flew for 16 minutes before making a second landing.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal%C3%A9v_Flight_262

This was probably possible due to the Tu-154 landing gear pods, into which the wheels retract during flight, which acted as sleds and shielded the landing gear, wing and flaps, as well as the Tu-154's tail-mounted trijet engine configuration and high thrust-to-weight ratio.